# Растяжение текста в TextView, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, textview

Привет, не могу придумать как сделать растяжение текста на всю ширину экрана в TextView, в конце строки всегда остаются большие пробелы. Надо сделать как это делается в Microsoft Word. Работаю в Android Studio, язык - java.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите свойства элемента TextView

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный виджет `TextView` не поддерживает выравнивание по ширине.

Как вариант, можно использовать сторонние библиотеки, например, [TextJustify](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также, выровнять текст по ширине можно с помощью [`WebView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314724/7129209).

Comment: пробовал использовать данную библиотеку, но с ней заметно замедляется скорость работы, особенно, если текста много. Может есть еще какие нибудь библиотеки?